# How to structure an app that has several versions per customer?

Tags: angularjs, architecture, modularity

Recently, the company I work for has given me the task of unifying 2 angularjs apps into one.
While I'm trying to wrap my head around it, here are the details:
- The two apps share quite a bit of common logic
- One of the apps (main one) is public facing, the other is made for a specific customer.
- Each app currently uses it's own database, this is because the customer's app is more complex and requires more data.
- Some of the common logic of the public app is being overwritten by the customer app due to the nature of it.
As an example, the login page is pretty simple in "public" but would have an extra layer of validating a registration code in "customer" and fetching the right data from the DB for this code.

I am trying to figure out how to I unify them both into 1 app, while having the ability to throttle between app modes or something similar

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to tackle this using [DDD (Domain Driven Design)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). Make a clear cut of the domain for both apps. For instance, if you encounter 2 user models in 2 different domains, as this is the case, you want to differentiate between the two of them.

Where this won't give you a framework to structure your application, it will provide a clear mindset on how to structure your application and correctly naming and identifying your contexts, domain and models.

Having clear domains should make a clear cut on which models can access X resources in the database.

Throttling is also an option, but I would only do it this way if I wouldn't have to maintain one of the versions. If the development branches only towards one, deprecating the other, then it is a reasonable solution, but maintaining 2 development branches this way is **very** painful.

Comment: Currently we have 2 domains (Something like public.myapp.com & customer1.myapp.com).

I'm curious to see a practical example for my example of the login (for customer1, the user is required to enter a unique key he received earlier from the customer, before being able to login). Would be great to help me wrap my head around it.

As for the login: If I would make it dependent on the domain. It wouldn't be just the view, but also the initialization of services (ready to receive the token from the db etc).